# CDN Image Redirects (avoiding redirect loop w/ htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, cdn

I have everything up and running on AWS Cloudfront CDN, the only issue I've hit is regarding my image files. They all display as wanted, but the old versions don't force redirect.

**For example:**
An image @ `http://domain.com/images/image.jpg` will direct and display at `http://cdn.domain.com/images/image.jpg`, but the previous version without the subdomain is accessible too.

I know it sounds a little tedious, but all the "juice" that was going to the previous image isn't going to the new image because it's not forcing that redirect. Ideally anytime I put `http://domain.com/images/image.jpg` in the browser I'd want it to redirect to `http://cdn.domain.com/images/image.jpg`. Every fix I've found online will create a loop though since it doesn't read whats before `domain.com`.

I know there's a solid way of doing this redirect in htaccess to just the jpegs in the images folder that aren't already redirected to the `cdn.` subdomain, but I can't find it anywhere online.  **Any help would be immensely appreciated.**

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to the document root of `domain.com`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(png|gif|jpe?g))$ http://cdn.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That seems perfect outside of the ^domain\.com on the second line (& ] at the end, which I know was just a typo). I think that's whats creating a loop since both 'cdn.domain.com' & 'domain.com' would be redirected. Regex is definitely not my forte, but is there a way to explicitly redirect only if the 'cdn' isn't already there?

Comment: The `^` in front of domain ensures that it is the beginning of the match. `cdn.domain.com` will not match that regex

Comment: I used your code and adjusted it to...    `RewriteEngine On    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^domain\.com$ [NC]    RewriteRule ^(.+\.(png|gif|jpe?g))$ http://cdn.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]`   Seems to be working - Does that make sense to you though? I don't want to break anything inadvertently.